# Linux screen push command error

Tags: linux, sh, gnu-screen

```
#!/bin/sh

SERVER=$1

RCON=$2
echo "$SERVER"
echo "$RCON"
sudo -u flash screen -r $SERVER -X stuff "$RCON"`echo -ne '\015'`
```

Guys do you see something wrong with this code? The main concept in the script is to push a command to a opened screen session.

In particular, it's expected to execute a command into opened screen session.

The script echoes the two vars, but when I open the screen, the command $RCON isn't executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replaced

```
#!/bin/sh
```

with

```
#!/bin/bash
```